# how to run cron hook after a week

Tags: 7, cron

i have created a module to hook Drupal cron system and the function in my module is being executed on every cron run, which is perfect.

I need this hooked cron function to run only once weekly without scheduling the default Drupal cron job .
Any help on this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the variety of cron modules that set intervals, like Elysia cron.

https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron

Comment: Thank you. Nice module. Exactly what i was looking for. BTW, i did find my cron hook in the settings tab "admin/config/system/cron" may be added by this module. And i did configure the hook to run after a week. But on the status page it shows a PAUSE icon which means " Job is disabled by settings, and won't run until enabled again" . So really will it run after a week ?

Comment: sorry, i ticked the "disabled" icon next to the cron job.

Comment: @brainHax I personally use [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)